# Kriging interpolation with blocks as barriers for street level visualization in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, interpolation, kriging, barriers

I'm trying to do Kriging interpolation with blocks as barriers for street level visualisation, but I can't realise how I can do this. I already have the barriers polygons, data and all.

But can I do Kriging interpolation with barriers in ArcMap?

Answer (score 1):

I Have to say that this is very limited information to work with and the question seems a bit too general, but I would guess the following will be the solution to what you're asking:

- Create an inverse of your barrier feature class: by clipping it from a rectangle feature class of the total extent of your research area
- Use the Kriging tool in ArcMap (SA license required), set input values as your input data (presumably) point feature class
- Before clicking "OK", click the environments button in the lower right side. Unfold "Raster Analysis" and set the Mask to the inverse of your barriers.

This will result in only the areas that are not defined as being a barrier, will be used in the Kriging calculation:

> Setting an analysis mask means that processing will only occur on locations that fall within the mask, and all locations outside of it will be assigned to NoData in the output.
>   The Mask environment applies to ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension and ArcGIS Geostatistical Analyst extension tools that output a raster. It also applies to tools in the ArcGIS 3D Analyst extension **Raster Interpolation**, Raster Math, Raster Reclass, and Raster Surface toolsets that output a raster.